# SQL Server 2008: generic convert to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a little problem in my query. My database at my local development server is running with French date format (`dd/mm/yyyy`) but my release server is on North American format (`mm/dd/yyyy`).

So this throws an error

```
SELECT CodPeriodoInsc, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, FechaDesde, 103) AS FechaDesde, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, FechaHasta, 103) AS FechaHasta 
FROM SedesPeriodosInscripcion
WHERE FechaDesde <= '25/06/2012'
```

But it works on development, and this works on release

```
SELECT CodPeriodoInsc,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, FechaDesde, 103) AS FechaDesde, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, FechaHasta, 103) AS FechaHasta 
FROM SedesPeriodosInscripcion
WHERE FechaDesde <= '06/25/2012'
```

But it doesn't work on development.

Is there a way I can make the query work on both databases?

Comment: First of all, you should use `VARCHAR(10)` or `CHAR(10)` for that matter. And second, use `YYYYMMDD` format for dates, its the only one that's not ambiguous, it doesn't depend on the server configuration

Comment: And don't use char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar without length. Ever. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: You should be using ISO format for your dates, as others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick a format and use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

But you could always just pick a canonical format for your date literals like: yyyyMMdd, which in your case would be '20120625'  These are never ambiguous (not even for humans).

or use an [ISO format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) to construct a date if you are using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @gosukiwi Which solution? To use `SET DATEFORMAT` differently on each server? Are you going to have to keep different versions of your code and know which version to deploy to every server, and accommodate that when regional settings change?

Comment: @gosukiwi That is not an optimal solution. Are you really going to have different versions of your code deployed on all of your servers? Why not *FIX* it by not using ambiguous date formats in the first place?

Comment: The code is not mine, is part of a huge project I honestly dont care, I just want to fix it. It will run on any hosting I upload so I think it works just fine. If I would have made that code, I would store the date as unix timestamps.

Comment: @gosukiwi I'm not sure why out of all the options I presented you picked the worst one.  If you are going to have to pick one of the versions of your code above, why not pick one with a canonical and unambiguous date format.

Answer (score 5):

If you pass in `05/06/2012`, how is your code supposed to know if that means May 6 or June 5? It can't.

The solution is to stop passing/storing dates in these formats in the first place. If you pass in `20120605` that's June 5th on all of your servers, regardless of the regional settings, collation, language, dateformat settings, etc...

So you should always say:

```
WHERE FechaDesde <= '20120625'
```